# Use array_filter() or array_intersect() to filter 2-dimensional array by one column using a 1-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, filter, callback, array-intersect

I'm trying to filter my first array by my second array.  I want to filter every person whose age is `22`,`25`,`35`, or `40`.  I have these whitelisted values store in an `$a2`

```
$a1 = [
    ['name' => 'mike',  'age' => 18],
    ['name' => 'james', 'age' => 22],
    ['name' => 'sarah', 'age' => 35],
    ['name' => 'ken',   'age' => 29],
];

$a2 = [22, 25, 35, 40];
```

I tried `array_intersect()` like:

```
$results = array_intersect($a2, $a1['age']);
var_dump($results);
```

And `array_filter()` but without success.

My desired output is:

```
[
    ['name' => 'james', 'age' => 22],
    ['name' => 'sarah', 'age' => 35]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

`array_uintersect()` is the first thing that comes to mind -- it allows you to compare the intersecting values between two arrays.  The fact that you have arrays of different depths means that you will need a custom callback.  Within that callback, you cannot be sure that `$a1` values will be represented in temporary variable `$a`, nor sure that `$a2` values will be represented in `$b`.  To properly handle each iteration, check for an `age` key else fall back to the base variable).

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/aW7gq))

```
$a1 = [
    ['name' => 'mike',  'age' => 18],
    ['name' => 'james', 'age' => 22],
    ['name' => 'sarah', 'age' => 35],
    ['name' => 'ken',   'age' => 29],
];
            
$a2 = [22, 25, 35, 40];

var_export(
    array_uintersect(
        $a1,
        $a2,
        fn($a, $b) => ($a['age'] ?? $a) <=> ($b['age'] ?? $b)
    )
);
```

---

Alternatively, a more concise approach involves making iterated calls of `in_array()` inside of an `array_filter()` call.  Generally, I strongly advise against making iterated calls of `in_array()` because `in_array()` is one of the slowest ways to make checks on array values.  Depending on the actual size of the two input arrays, the following snippet may perform better or worse than `array_uintersect()` -- I did not do any benchmarks.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/oKRGn))

```
var_export(
    array_filter($a1, fn($row) => in_array($row['age'], $a2))
);
```

Answer (score -1):

array_intersect and array_diff don't work well with multi dimensional arrays.

try this and see how work:

```
$a = [1,2,3,4];
$b = [2,7,8,9];
var_dump(array_intersect($a,$b));
```

the result should be [2].
if you work with multidimensional arrays and you only interesting in one column of arrays do first:

```
$age = array_column($a1,'age');
```

and then

```
var_dump(array_intersect($age,$a2));
```

Comment: i need the full index to array , so i need the persons name as well.